# Clojure NullPointerException on for loop

Tags: clojure, lisp, idioms

I'm about to pull out my hair on this one.

For some context, I'm implementing a simple algorithm in Clojure. assume the following data structures

```
(def inf Double/POSITIVE_INFINITY)
(def min-dist (atom {:1 {:1 0 :2 4} :2 {:1 4 :2 0 :3 5} :3 {:2 5 :3 0}}))
(def vertexes [:1 :2 :3])
```

The following code will crash after the first iteration:

```
(for [k vertexes i vertexes j vertexes]
  ((println (str " " i " " k " "j))
   (if (> (get-in @min-dist [i j] inf) (+ (get-in @min-dist [i k] inf) (get-in @min-dist [k j] inf)) )
     (do
       ;;do some stuff
       (println "bla"))
   )))
```

With the following output:

> :1 :1 :1 NullPointerException
>   user.core/eval7683/iter--7675--7684/fn--7685/iter--7677--7686/fn--7687/iter--7679--7688/fn--7689/fn--7690
>   (form-init1244434853692676604.clj:2)

I do understand that I'm probably violating some references during the `if` here. But I'm new to clojure and have no idea on what I'm doing wrong here. Something to do with the triple-for over the same seq?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra pair of brackets on the second line. You probably want to add **do** there and it will work.

Comment: this happens when you are learning Clojure, will gone with practice :)